# Can't retrieve MongoDB to local drive using SCP from AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, strapi

I have a Docker container using Strapi (which used MondoDB) on a now defunct AWS EC2. I need the content off that server - it can't run because it's too full. So i've tried to retrieve all the files using SCP - which worked a treat apart from download the database content (the actual stuff i need - Strapi and docker book up fine, but because it has to database content, it treats it as a new instance).

Every time i try to download the contents on db from AWS i get 'permission denied'

I'm using SCP something like this

```
scp -i /directory/to/***.pem -r user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:strapi-docker/* /your/local/directory/files/to/download
```

Does anyone know how i can get this entire docker container running locally with the database content?

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily change permissions (recursively) on the directory in question to be world-readable using `chmod`.